Understand OpenSSL's AES-256-CBC encrypt/decrypt - IV issue
There's openssl code that I try to understand why it is working.
See this code below.
It has encryption and decryption functions over OpenSSL's AES-256-CBC cipher.
It also contains simple main() program for test - it encrypts the given string from the command line, print the encrypted result, decrypt it back, print the decrypted result.
If you run it, you'll see it decrypts back to the original text.
Same key provided by main() for both encrypt/decrypt is a simple 32 bytes string as required by AES-CBC.
The encrypt generates internally the random 16 bytes initial vector.
I compiled and tested in it in Linux using RedHat 8 which uses openssl-.1.1.1k.
To compile: g++ -o aes_cbc aes_cbc.cxx -lcrypto
To run: ./aes_cbc "hello world test"
The decryption result is correct (same as the input), but I don't understand why.
Explanation: same IV (initial vector) should be used in encryption and decryption, right? But I do not see it written into the encrypted result by any mean. Instead, the decryption also set its own IV randomly.
Only clue I have is that the encrypt code prepend the text to encrypt by 16 bytes local buffer (initialized to "1234567890123456", but it could be any 16 bytes).
So, why it is working with encrypt/decrypt use same key but different IV?
// To compile: g++ -o aes_cbc aes_cbc.cxx -lcrypto
// To run: ./aes_cbc "hello world test"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
//#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
//#include <openssl/bio.h>
//#include <openssl/buffer.h>

#define THE_ALGORITHM           "aes-256-cbc"
#define AES_CBC_IV_LENGTH       16
#define BUFF_SIZE           1024

using namespace std;

static bool all_ciphers_added = false;

int aes_256_cbc_encrypt(const string& text, const unsigned char* key, string& output)
{
    int data_len = 16 + text.size();
    char *data = (char *)malloc(data_len);
    if (data == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    memcpy(data, "1234567890123456", 16);
    memcpy(data+16, text.c_str(), text.size());

    if (!all_ciphers_added) {
        OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
        all_ciphers_added = true;
    }

    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname(THE_ALGORITHM);
    if (cipher == NULL) {
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    BIO* encryptor = BIO_new(BIO_f_cipher());
    if (encryptor == NULL) {
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char iv[AES_CBC_IV_LENGTH];
    RAND_bytes(iv, AES_CBC_IV_LENGTH);
    BIO_set_cipher(encryptor, cipher, key, iv, 1);

    BIO* base64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if (base64 == NULL) {
        BIO_free_all(encryptor);
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    // Ask the base64 encoder to put the entire encoded message in one line.
    BIO_set_flags(base64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

    BIO* memory = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if (memory == NULL) {
        BIO_free_all(encryptor);
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    BIO_push(encryptor, base64);
    BIO_push(base64, memory);

    if (BIO_write(encryptor, data, data_len) != data_len) {
        BIO_free_all(encryptor);
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    if (BIO_flush(encryptor) != 1) {
        BIO_free_all(encryptor);
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }

    char* mem_data;
    int mem_data_size;
    mem_data_size = BIO_get_mem_data(memory, &mem_data);

    output = string(mem_data, mem_data_size);

    BIO_free_all(encryptor);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}

int aes_256_cbc_decrypt(const string& text, const unsigned char* key, string& output)
{
    if (!all_ciphers_added) {
        OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
        all_ciphers_added = true;
    }

    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname(THE_ALGORITHM);
    if (cipher == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    BIO* memory = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)text.c_str(), -1);
    if (memory == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    BIO* base64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if (base64 == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Ask base64 decoder to read the data without waiting for a new line character.
    BIO_set_flags(base64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

    BIO* decryptor = BIO_new(BIO_f_cipher());
    if (decryptor == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char iv[AES_CBC_IV_LENGTH];
    RAND_bytes(iv, AES_CBC_IV_LENGTH);
    BIO_set_cipher(decryptor, cipher, key, iv, 0);

    BIO_push(decryptor, base64);
    BIO_push(base64, memory);

    char buff[BUFF_SIZE+1];
    int len;

    while ((len = BIO_read(decryptor, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        buff[len] = '\0';
        output += buff;
    }

    BIO_free_all(decryptor);

    if (len == 0) {
        if (output.size() > 16) {
            output = output.substr(16);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else { // len < 0
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s {text to encrypt}\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char* text = argv[1];
    printf("Initial text  : %s\n", text);

    // 32 bytes key as requested by AES-256-CBC.
    const unsigned char* key = (const unsigned char *)"12345678901234567890123456789012";

    string encrypted_text;
    if (aes_256_cbc_encrypt(text, key, encrypted_text)) {
      return -1;
    }
    printf("Encrypted text: %s\n", encrypted_text.c_str());

    string decrypted_text;
    if (aes_256_cbc_decrypt(encrypted_text, key, decrypted_text)) {
      return -1;
    }
    printf("Decrypted text: %s\n", decrypted_text.c_str());

    return 0;
}


I tried to increase the 16 bytes to which the text to encrypt is prepend to 20 bytes ("12345678901234567890", and replace all 16's to 20's).
It still working correct.
I tried to decrease the 16 bytes to 15, 14, 13, 12, etc.
The decrypt yield either "partially correct" or completely incorrect result.
It look like that these reserved 16 bytes that preceding the text to encrypt is somehow holding the IV?! But that's impossible because the encryptor feed with data_len = 16 + text.size();
Btw,
If you comment out this code at the decrypt function:
        if (output.size() > 16) {
            output = output.substr(16);
        }

the decrypted first 16 bytes that trimmed by above code is garbage, not the "1234567890123456".
Is it possible that the AES-CBC encryption is also "writing" the 16 bytes IV?
Miko

I've only had a quick look at the code, but it seems that during encryption you use a 16 byte block before the actual plaintext, which you discard after decryption. The wrong IV corrupts the first 16 bytes, i.e. just this block, and since you discard this block after decryption, you do not notice the corruption, i.e. decryption works.

However, this only works for the CBC mode, as in this mode an incorrect IV only ever corrupts the first block, see CBC diagram.

AES(-or-any)-CBC does not 'write' the IV but it does USE the IV, and the IV must be the same for decrypt as for encrypt. You use two random values which will not be the same in the lifetime of the universe. Correct schemes either choose a random IV and transmit/store it along with the data -- often simply prefixed, but there are other ways -- or derive the IV at both ends in a deterministic way unpredictable by any adversary, such as encrypting sequence numbers by a shared key. PS: it hasn't been necessary to explicitly load algorithms (or errorstrings) since 1.1.0 in 2016.

Thank you. I wasn't are of the low level detail - "The wrong IV corrupts the first 16 bytes, i.e. just this block". I'll read more into the CBC diagram. So matter of fact, without add these 16 bytes before, they would have add the result also the IV. They didn't send the IV but added instead unused 16-bytes. So in terms of "encrypted length, nothing actually reduced, interesting for me. Thanks Dave for the comments regarding loading the algorithms...
